# memory_order: acquire/release reversed pattern

Tags: c++, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Might be stupid but rather being asked than regret for the rest of my life.

The standard pattern of `std::atomic::load` and `std::atomic::store` would be
something like this

N.B.: assume that in **all** examples below the initial value for `data` is `0`

writer:

```cpp
data = 42;
sync_after_write.store(1, memory_order_release);
```

reader:

```cpp
while (sync_after_write.load(memory_order_acquire) != 1) {}
assert(data == 42); // must hold
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to express the reversed pattern where sync happens before storing the data value. The idea is to ensure that the writer hasn't started
modifying the data and the reader still has the original value of it.

Something along these lines

writer:

```cpp
sync_before_write.store(1, /* which memory access ? */); // we want to prevent subsequent
                                                         // stores to appear before this statement
data = 42;
```

reader:

```cpp
data_copy = data;
if (sync_before_write.load(/* which memory access ? */) == 0) { // we want to prevent previous
                                                                // loads to appear after this statement
  assert(data_copy == 0); // in other words since sync_before_write is zero then
                          // the writer hasn't started modifying the data value
                          // yet and it stays to be zero (original)
}
```

---

Edit: I should admit it was not clear from the beginning, `data` is NOT atomic and may require multiple cycles to read/write from/to

Comment: You have a data race on `data`. It's not an atomic variable, right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Correct, not atomic, may take a lot of cycles to read/write. And yes, I expect a data race on `data`

Comment: Then I believe it's always going to be UB, technically.

Comment: If you want to detect possible tearing after the fact, the SeqLock pattern is useful: 2 stores from the writer, and load before/after access in the readers.  Although it's kind of a hack because it lets data-race UB happen.  (Making the payload `volatile` is enough in real implementations, although even that is inconvenient in C++.  Even non-volatile is probably fine in practice if you use sufficient barriers to get it to make safe asm.)  [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54611003)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. Indeed I seemed to came up with a similar pattern myself. A writer can indeed do two stores before and after writing to `data` and the reader can do two loads before and after reading from `data`. But I got lost in proving that this is guaranteed to work as I think it formally won't :-)

Comment: Yeah, ISO C++'s formal memory model won't guarantee it, but real HW memory models can because coherent cache exists even if nothing is doing acq/rel synchronization, and the load(s) or store(s) of non-atomic `data` have an ordering even if if they might tear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this if both `data` and `sync` are `std::atomic` so you can use `acquire`/`release` on both.  If you can't do that, you'll have to do something else.

Detecting potential tearing in `data` after already copying it is something C++ doesn't support, but is what the [seqlock](/questions/tagged/seqlock) pattern does, and it is possible to hack that up in C++ in a way that compiles to working asm with real compilers for real ISAs.

---

To simplify your problem, you have one thread with

```cpp
sync = 1;
data = 42;
```

... and another thread with

```cpp
data_copy = data;
if (sync == 0)
    assert(data_copy == 0);
```

This requires only [acquire/release ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), due to two relationships:

- `sync = 1` is [sequenced before](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#def:sequenced_before) `data = 42` and thus [happens before](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:happens_before) the other
- `data = 42` may [synchronize with](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:synchronize_with) `data_copy = data`.

If `data = 42` [synchronizes with](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:synchronize_with) `data_copy = data`, then `sync = 1` [happens before](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:happens_before) `data_copy = data` because the [happens before](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:happens_before) relationship is acyclic.

An intuitive model for acquire/release is that each acquiring thread sees a certain point on the timeline of other threads' release operations.
It is not possible to see release operations in reversed order.
If `sync == 0`, then `sync = 1` has not yet happened and `data = 42` has not yet happened either.

---

*Note: Perhaps you should use something like a `std::mutex` if you can't make both atomic.*

Comment: This would also require `data` to be `std::atomic<>`, so you do `seq_cst` loads and stores on *both* variables, not just `sync`.  We need them both to participate in the total order of SC operations.  In the OP's code, I suspect they're thinking of plain `int data`, even though if their condition is false, that means a race *did* happen.  (ISO C++ makes it inconvenient to write SeqLocks or other patterns that rely on detecting a race and not using the possibly-torn load).

Comment: In practice making just `sync` use `seq_cst` might work even on CPUs like PowerPC [that can do IRIW reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see).  But not on AArch64 where `seq_cst` loads/stores are as weak as allowed by ISO C++, e.g. an SC store (`stlr`) can reorder with later relaxed and plain stores (`str`), and with later loads other than SC loads (`ldr` and `ldapr` acquire loads).

Comment: @PeterCordes ah yeah, I didn't see OP's comment that `data` was plain instead of an atomic variable when I wrote my answer. I've clarified that both must be atomic for this to work. If `data` cannot be made atomic, is there anything other than `std::mutex` that would let this be properly synchronized?

Comment: I had to guess from how they used it, and the name before their comment.  In terms of strictly correct ISO C++ with no data-race UB, I don't think there's anything they can do.  What they want (copy efficiently and then detect possible tearing after the fact) is basically equivalent to what the SeqLock pattern needs, as I commented under the question.  Unfortunately ISO C++ doesn't offer a way to write that, other than declaring the payload as a bunch of `atomic<size_t>` relaxed chunks or something and using that to copy object-representations; real compilers won't use SIMD for wide copies

Comment: @PeterCordes Excuse me not being precise, indeed I didn't consider `data` to be atomic. I edited my original post. Thank you for valuable inputs. I need to digest them in the meantime.