# how to pass reference asynchronously between threads? With Observer?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, producer-consumer

How do I ensure that:

1.)  `localThread` and `remoteThread` run independent of each other?

2.)  pass messages between `localThread` and `remoteThread`?

Specifically, a String object from `localThread` needs to "percolate" up to `Telnet` through, I think it's known as, a call-back.  However, there's not really anything, per se, for `Telnet` to `observe`.  It's an anonymous reference to `LocalIO`, and I don't see that explicitly providing a reference helps.

I've read about `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` until my head exploded, all I came away with was that it doesn't seem to apply.  For these two threads, they should continue to run regardless of what the other thread is doing.  However, there needs to be some mechanism to pass object references between the threads...

```
public class Telnet {

    public Telnet() throws InterruptedException {
        startThreads();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Telnet();
    }

    public void startThreads() throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1, true);

        Thread localThread = new Thread(new LocalIO());
        Thread remoteThread = new Thread(new RemoteIO());

        localThread.start();
        remoteThread.start();
    }
}
```

The threads themselves are as follows.  `LocalIO`:

```
public class LocalIO implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner;
        String line;
        while (true) {
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            out.println("\n\nyou entered\t\"" + line + "\"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

`RemoteIO`:

```
public class RemoteIO implements Runnable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemoteIO.class.getName());
    final String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
    final int port = 3000;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.fine(host + port);
        int byteOfData;
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream ouputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            while ((byteOfData = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.print((char) byteOfData);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Keeping in mind that `RemoteIO` never closes its connection and runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found:

```
public class RemoteConnection extends Observable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemoteConnection.class.getName());
    private final Socket socket;
    private final BufferedInputStream in;
    private final BufferedOutputStream out;
    private final static String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

    public RemoteConnection(String host, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }

    public void write(Deque<String> commands) throws IOException {
        String command;
        while (!commands.isEmpty()) {
            command = commands.pop();
            out.write(command.concat("\r\n").getBytes(Charset.forName(UTF8)));
            log.info(command);
        }
        out.flush();
    }

    void read() {  //probably should use BufferedStream to better effect..?
        Thread readRemote = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                char ch;
                int i;
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        i = in.read();
                        ch = (char) i;
                        sb.append(ch);
                        System.out.print(ch);
                        if (i == 13) {
                            setChanged();
                            notifyObservers(sb.toString());
                            log.fine(sb.toString());
                            sb = new StringBuilder();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        log.fine(ioe.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        readRemote.start();
    }
}
```

By reorganizing the threading, this approximates a poor-mans telnet, with asynchronous threads for i/o.  I think reading from the console was blocking...something...

I really don't know why this works but the other approaches didn't.  I would've preferred to have the main class start and handle threads, and pass references between the threads, but that just didn't work despite using the various solutions offered here.

LocalConnection has a similar threading approach.

Answer (score 2):

The concurrent package is very helpful for this sort of thing:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

For example you can just give each thread a ConcurrentLinkedQueue and they can check the queue to see if there is anything to act on whenever they please. Meanwhile other threads can add new objects to the queue whenever they please.

Comment: lol, yeah, but in all seriousness, and I will check it out, but is there an **asynchronous** API?

Comment: What I just described is asynchronous. Neither thread waits for the other, they just get on with what they are doing and check for new messages whenever they feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one essential difference in the programming paradigm your code can adopt:

- *synchronous* mode: the receiving end runs an endless loop which explicitly takes items off a concurrent queue, blocking when there are no items ready;
- *asynchronous* mode: the receiving end submits a callback to an item exchange mechanism. This callback is called for every item which arrives from the producer thread.

The *Observer* pattern may loosely apply to the latter case, but not to the former.

Also note that in the latter case, the "item exchange mechanism" is usually implemented in the synchronous mode.

Comment: You can implement your own event dispatch loop and then submit a callback to it. It wolud be a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what yu are trying to do, but if you want to exchange data between threads, you need a volatile variable to make sure changes are seen by other threads. AtomicReferences are non-blocking and provide some API that might help here.

Comment: current code is on github:  https://github.com/THUFIR/MudSocketClient/tree/master/src/mudsocketclient  it's a bit different now, of course.  I'm not sure what you mean by volatile here, nor atomic references. From what I read, a POJO CubbyHole should be able to go between two threads (?). Or, rather, accessible by two threads.  However, I seem to be in a deadlock (?) where only the Producer thread keeps running -- or perhaps it blocks the Consumer.  I'm not sure.

Comment: With non-volatila POJOs, there is no guarantee by the jvm if and when changes made to the POJO by one thread will be visible to the other. Atomic*** classes are based on that and put a nice API around it. In general though, and geting back to your orginal question, you can only make sure that two threads run independent of each other if they don't share anything. But in your case, they do.

Comment: So, in your example code, CubbyHole's message field should be volatile. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259745/volatile-variable-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I would give you plus ten if I could.  I'm **assuming** this is the solution.  LOL, I forgot about "volatile" as a keyword.

Comment: if you think this is the solution, there are ways to flag this answer :)

Comment: oh, pardon, turns it wasn't a solution which worked for me.  I think the problem was actually i/o blocking unrelated.   see https://github.com/THUFIR/MudSocketClient/tree/master/src/mudsocketclient  I'll post what worked for me as a "solution".