# Will volatile protect me from all behind-the-scenes multi-threading hazards?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, volatile

I used to think there are only two multithreading hazards:

1. *Race condition*: a thread reads `x`, and before it can write back another thread write `x`.
2. *Unstable state*: a thread writes `x` and `y`, but between those two writes another thread reads `x`'s new value and `y`'s old value even though those variables should change together.

I figured that if I can reason these things can't happen, I don't need to synchronize. But from [an argument over the D language forums](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/fofbrlqruxbevnxchxdp@forum.dlang.org?page=3#post-aikahcfpcfadfjqcsicq:40forum.dlang.org) I learned there can be other hazards from how the compiler, the CPU and the memory work behind the scenes:

1. Both compiler and CPU can change the order of instruction in a way that does not affect single-threading execution but can break my reasoning about non-synchronized thread safety. For example, an object can be allocated and assigned to the thread-shared variable and only then the constructor will be called. It shouldn't matter in single-threading, but with multithreading another thread can now access the uninitialized object.
2. Caching means that even if the order of operations is correct, the synching between the global memory and the local caches both threads use can mess with the order one thread can see another thread's changes.
3. Unaligned pointer-sized writes are not atomic, and in some architectures even aligned ones might not be atomic, so the pointer itself might be corrupted(=in unstable state) when the other thread reads it, because the thread that written it only written half it's bytes.

I now work on an Android project and once again I face a similar problem - I can reason about some functions being safe from race conditions and unstable states, but not about those three behind-the-scenes hazards.

I've encountered the Java `volatile` member fields, and from what I gather it uses memory barriers to prevent the CPU from messing with order of execution(and obviously the compiler won't mess with it if it prevents the CPU from doing so) so it should solve the first hazard. But what about the other two?

- Does it solve the caching problem? Isn't the caching under the responsibility of the OS? Does it signal the OS, forcing it to refresh the cache?
- Does it solve the non-atomic-writes problem? Does it force variable alignment and uses the JVM's runtime knowledge to use synchronization when even aligned pointer-sized writes are not atomic?

In other words - if I can reason that race conditions and unstable states are not a problem, and mark the shared variable as `volatile`, is it safe to not use synchronization?

Comment: Volatile writes are all atomic. Non-volatile writes also except for long and double.

Comment: @assylias Is this guaranteed on all architectures?

Comment: @Arye yes: the Java Memory Model is architecture-independent. However long and double assignment may be atomic on some architectures but there is no guarantee so you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first and the third issue (some link about the first one would be nice if you're sure about it) but I'm sure it fixes your second issue because volatile ensures the flush of the local cache.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259745/volatile-variable-in-java) or [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) about this topic.

**Update**

I think I found the perfect link for your question:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz2vjymNleY

**1. About reordering**

> By the way use of volatile keyword also prevents compiler or JVM from reordering of code or moving away them from synchronization barrier.

**2. About caching**

> Volatile keyword in Java is used as an indicator to Java compiler and  Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory

**3. About atomic read and write**

> In Java reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared using Java volatile keyword (including long and double variables).

Comment: About the first hazard - [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) explains how `volatile` adds memory barriers to protect from reordering, so it's safe. Since you say the it also solves the second hazard, all that's left is the third hazard.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it should provide good protection(after all - that's it's purpose!). I just wanted to make sure.