# Is it good to separate game thread and display thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

It is the first time I want to write a java game, and I chose to do a Snake Line.

I learnt from a piece of source code from online. It updates the game states and displays in one thread. I changed around that code, and when I changed the FPS (from 60 to 30), animation slows down. More to this, the game behavior changes too. It is duck shooting game, and the space between ducks get narrower.

So I decided to separate the game thread and the display thread to avoid the above problem. But then I realize it brings out the concurrency problem which will be all over the place.

So as the title indicates, is it good to separate game thread and display thread? What is the common practice and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the changes you experience, it sounds like you are using *frame* as a unit of time measurement. Or, more precisely, you use *pixel/frame*(or something like that) for velocity and *second* for time.

This might be OK for a simple game like yours, ones that are light enough on the system resources so that the delay between frames you specify in the code is practically the same as the real delay, meaning you are in complete control over the FPS. When the game get heavier and modern systems can no longer guarantee that property, you have a problem.

The solution is usually not to separate the game and display loops to separate threads, but to not use frames as unit of measurement for game mechanics calculations. Instead, each frame measure the time from the previous frame and use that value for the calculations, eg. multiply it by the speed to know how much to move a game object in this frame.

Not that separating those loops is such a bad idea. You don't get concurrency problems "all over the place", since the interaction between the game logic and the display shouldn't be "all over the place". The interaction should be one-way: the game loop writes data and the display loop reads it. That means you shouldn't have race conditions, but you can still get [other multithreading hazards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346385/will-volatile-protect-me-from-all-behind-the-scenes-multi-threading-hazards), which you can solve with `volatile` variables.